# SpringBoot Swagger2 rest API documentation is not loading

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger-2.0

I am just trying out to get the documentation for my small REST API written in in spring with swagger2 inclusion. When i try to access my swagger page the following error is shown in browser console.

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Sep 25 21:09:08 IST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

My code snippets are below mentioned.

```
    package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/rooms")
@Api(value="rooms", tags=("rooms"))
public class RoomController {

    @Autowired
    private RoomRepositery roomRepo;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ApiOperation(value="Get All Rooms", notes="Get all rooms in the system", nickname="getRooms")
    public List<Room> findAll(@RequestParam(name="roomNumber", required=false)String roomNumber){
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(roomNumber)) {
            return Collections.singletonList(roomRepo.findByRoomNumber(roomNumber));
        }
        return (List<Room>) this.roomRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

App class

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.any;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class RoomServiceApp {

    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("Room").select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.demo"))
                .paths(any()).build().apiInfo(new ApiInfo("Room Services",
                        "A set of services to provide data access to rooms", "1.0.0", null,
                        new Contact("Frank Moley", "https://twitter.com/fpmoles", null),null, null));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RoomServiceApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am not able to found what i am missing here. Can any one help me out?

Thanks

Comment: have you solved this issue yet? I have the same issue which I can't identify

Comment: No. I have moved away from this as i was only playing that time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use http://localhost:9090/swagger-ui.html for swagger UI and http://localhost:9090/v2/api-docs?group=Room for JSON API.

I used the same code and find attached screenshot.

[image]

refer to [this](https://github.com/TheMaheshBiradar/spring-web-apps/tree/master/spring-swagger) project for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Request mapping at method level should have **URI path** like below for findAll method. Consumes and produces also required if there is input passed to method and output returned from method.

The reason is empty mapping value at method level will result in 'host:port/contextPath/' for which swagger will return 404.

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET }, value = "/roomList", consumes = {
        MediaType.ALL}, produces = { MediaType.ALL})
```